# jQuery Autocomplete plugin not working in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

My friends, I went through all the steps of building an autocomplete, but there is a problem in displaying the search results. Please see the image.

The information is read from the database but the view does not work properly. I am using version 4 of Bootstrap.

[image]

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

   <input type="text" id="SematYaShoghlBime" name="SematYaShoghlBime" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SematYaShoghlBime').autocomplete({
            source: '/Home/SearchInTaminJobs'
        });
    })
</script>

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchInTaminJobs()
{
    string term = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
    var query = _context.Citys.Where(Ad => Ad.CityName.Contains(term)).ToList();

        return Ok(query);
 
}

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example response of the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image the the autocomplete fields are rendered, however the text is missing. This is probably due to you returning a list of object through the API instead of a list of strings.

You can change your API like so to provide a list as a response:

```
   var query = _context.Citys.Where(Ad => Ad.CityName.Contains(term))
                              .Select(c => c.CityName)   //add this line...
                              .ToList();
```